# How can i define "A fully defined relationship" in JPA like .NET Entity Framework

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Entity Framework supports different define types. Examples: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

I want to define OneToMany like Example 4 (Convention 4) in JPA. How can i do this in JPA?

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CurrentGradeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentGradeId")] 
    public Grade CurrentGrade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{

    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

There is ForeignKey(CurrentGradeId) and EntityRefenrence(CurrentGrade) of Grade in StudentObject.

There is no difference beetween updating ForeignKey(CurrentGradeId) or updating EntityReference(CurrentGrade). Both point to same table column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about Spring and JPA, you can do the following

```
@Entity
public class Student
{
    @Id
    public int Id;

    public string Name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student") 
    public List<Grade> grades;

    // getters and setters and constructors
}

@Entity
public class Grade
{

    @Id
    public int GradeId;
    public string GradeName;

    @ManyToOne
    public Student student;

    // getters and setters and constructors
}
```

You would use the @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations as above.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I also want to define studentId like a field in Grade object. Because in some cases I will use the studentId field and in some cases the object reference(student).